# Haskell: summing up the elements of a list

Tags: list, haskell

I have to sum up the elements of a list like this for example:
if your input is `['a','b','c']`, the output should be `["a","ab","abc"]`.
But I have no idea how to code this... could somebody give me a hint?
I would be very grateful!

Comment: Hint? Fine: if these are [nonempty lists](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#t:NonEmpty), then you can just use the [duplicate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:duplicate) comonad method. (There is no real consistent way to define what the result should be for an empty list!) Seriously though, I doubt that this will help you much now, nor do I think any other answer we could give would help you as much as first reading some tutorials. I always recommend [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: Do you know about pattern matching yet?

Comment: A slightly easier hint might be to point you towards [`scanl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) ;)

Comment: An even easier hint would be to look in `Data.List` for `inits` and `tail`, which is how I would actually do it.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: `['a','b','c'] == "abc"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all those hints are fine but you probably struggle with those too

I would suggest you start from here:

```
sumList [] = []
sumList [x] = [[x]]
sumList (x:xs) = ... : map (...) (sumList xs)
```

and try to figure out what you have to put into both `...` (**hint** not the same ;))

the first line is only there to give some reasonable result for an empty list as input - you could remove it (recursion should not hit it)

The second one will do `[1] -> [[1]]`

Now you have to figure out what to do with more - here is an additional hint:

```
sumList [1,2]
{ 3. line - x = 1, xs = [2] }
= ... : map (...) (sumList [2])
{ 2. line }
= ... : map (...) [[2]]
```

now you *want*

```
= [[1],[1,2]]
```

so it look like you can do this with

```
first ... = [1]
second ... = map (prepend 1) to every list in [[2]]
```